# Removing Space HTML

Tags: html

At the bottom of my webpage, I have added a video.

https://www.rhythmstix.co.uk/software#content

There is now too much space between the video and the download "buttons" at the bottom. Can you help?

Section of HTML for that area in the link below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/20yx7tj2bokznlr/index.html?dl=0

I've added the following embed code which has seemingly added the extra space.

Play the video below to find out how to install and use the Rhythmstix Lesson Viewer and access Teacher Resources

Thanks so much

Rob

Edit

Thanks so much for all of your help - this has worked perfectly on desktop however I think the video is too wide for mobile devices as it’s now too lare for mobile devices and it just runs off the edge of the screen causing issues. Is there a correct setting for my embedded video which will be multi platform compliant? – Rob Reich-Storer just now    Edit    Delete

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] **in the question itself**

Answer (score 1):

There is a span with a large font size, which is causing the issue.

```
<span style="font-size:10em;">&nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<span style="font-size:10em;">&nbsp;</span>` tag if it is not require might remove space.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the span or lower the font size of it.

```
<div class="main">
<div class="bord-rad-yt-container" ....>

  <span style="font-size:10em;">&nbsp;</span> // remove this or lower the font size to something like '2em'
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help - this has worked perfectly on desktop however I think the video is too wide for mobile devices as it’s now too lare for  mobile devices and it just runs  off the edge of the screen causing issues. Is there a correct setting for my embedded video which will be multi platform compliant?